# Edit page before display in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Can remove div from html page in iFrame.
In the below code we are fetching html page and showing tht in iframe.. Can i remove  from the html page fetching below.

`<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
    document.write(['<iframe name="myfxbook_market" width="100%" height=' + height + ' frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" hspace="0" vspace="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src=' + "http://widgets.myfxbook.com/widgets/calendar.html"+ps+"></iframe>"].join(''));
}());
</script>"`

Or is there any other way to edit this page before display ?
Thanks for help.

Comment: remove the page? Just do not include the code?

Comment: It is code for widget am adding in my site.. just want to edit it little bit before adding.
It is fetching it from myfxbook.com. Thats not my site..

Comment: What do you want to edit a bit? The code inside the iframe or the code that generates the iframe...

Comment: You cannot modify the contents of the iFrame window with JavaScript unless you own both of these domains.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately, You’re not permitted to futz with iframes from other
>   sites.
>
> BUT, you can put it in a large iframe behind the rest of your page
>   with z-index css and a lot more CSS.

have a look at this; [jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)